# Fit videojs player in 16/8 div in react project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, video.js

I have a div with width 100% and height 50%. Basically it is a 16/8 ratio div. Now I want to fit video js player in it. The component which renders this 16/8 div is this (you can see the Player component inside video-container div

```
return (
            <div className={c.container}>
                <div className='video-section'>
                    <div className='video-container'>
                        *<Player/>*
                    </div>
```

css for video-container

```
.video-container
        width 100%
        background-color #000
        padding-bottom:  50%;
```

I have a Player component which is like this

```
assign(props, {
        ref: 'video',
        controls: true,
        width: "960", height: "600"
    });


return (
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <video {... props}>
            <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    </div>)
```

videoplayer.css

```
.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

.video-wrapper > video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I am getting this on my screen 
[image]
This is update till now

New update after editing

```
.video-container
            width 100%
```

and removing width and height from video tag.

[image]

What I want is this

[image]

index.js

```
return (
            <div className={c.container}>
                <div className='video-section'>
                    <div className='video-container'>
                        <Player/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='video-title'> {name} </div>
                    <div className='process-list'>
                        {
                            PROCESS_LIST.map((x,i)=> (
                                <div
                                    className='process-item'
                                    key={i}
                                    onClick={this.toHome.bind(this)}> {x} </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='details-section'>
                    <VideoDetails/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
:local(.container)
    display flex
    flex 1

    .video-section
        margin 24px
        flex 1
    .details-section
        margin 24px
        width 33vw
        flex-shrink 0
        display flex
        flex-direction column
// border-left 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid

    .video-container
        width 80%

    .video-title
        font-size 2.4em
        margin-top 4vh
        margin-bottom 4vh

    .video-section .process-list
        display flex
        width 100%

        .process-item
            flex 1
            background-color #D7D7D7
            padding 18px 30px
            font-size 1em
            text-align center
            border-radius 8px
            margin 0 4px
            cursor pointer
            &:hover
                background-color darken(@background-color, 10%)



:local(.container)
    .video-details-container
        flex 1
        display flex
        flex-direction column

    .comments-section, .tabbed-section
        min-height 100px
        background-color #fff
        border 1px rgba(#000, 0.12) solid
        box-shadow 0 4px 24px 0 rgba(#000, 0.12)
    .comments-section
        height 180px

    .flex-vertical
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        height 100%

    .flex-fill
        flex 1

    .tabbed-section
        flex 1
        margin-bottom 20px
        display flex
        flex-direction column
        .tab-content
            flex 1

    .table-footer, .comments-footer
        clearfix()
        text-align right
        padding 10px
        border-top 1px rgba(#000, 0.2) solid

    #comments-input
        flex 1
        border none
        padding 20px
        outline none


    .flags-table 
        .red-box
            width 16px
            height 16px
            margin 3px 5px
            background-color red
```

New Updates

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this approach by CSS. It's basically common problem and this is his common solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/t1gsrsu5/3

Simply render in React `wrapper div` and `video element`, and css will handle the ratio for you.

```
.playerDiv
   .video-wrapper
      video
```

the video will be in ratio 16:9 based on size of `.playerDiv.`

```css
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.video-wrapper > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrapper">
<video controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: So should I remove video-container div and it's css?

Comment: I edited the answer. Best solution will be, if the `Player` render the `.video-wrapper` and `video` element. (You don't need `PlayerLogic` at all). Then whenever you render `Player` video will be in 16:9 ratio relative to the parent div of the `Player`.

Comment: what should I do with the height and width of video. Should I set it to auto?

Comment: I am updating the question. I did what u suggested. But I am getting something else. Have a look

Comment: Video width is set by CSS (to 100%). Could you provide example of your implementation?

Comment: Yes. See the update ques. I changed everything on ques. I implemented things u asked me to.

Comment: You don't need to set an explicit size of the video. `<video controls ref='video'>
            <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>`. video-container should only center the video player?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133186/discussion-between-apurvg-and-jukben).

Comment: My guess is that you use flexbox wrongly. See this little example: https://jsfiddle.net/t1gsrsu5/

Comment: I did this and now I can the side component completely. But what it did is it shrinked side component to show it completely. Player is not changing it's size. That is the main problem I am facing. Player remains that big only

Comment: I followed your code. Pls see the latest image. Now all the components are in the screen. But player size remains same.

Comment: I'm running out of an ideas. I simply don't know what you mean by "remains same". https://jsfiddle.net/t1gsrsu5/3/ Maybe someone will understand better to your issue...

Comment: Glad to help, please approve my answer as correct then. :)

Comment: I have one issue in the solution you provided. The player in the jsfiddle is not with default skin. I want the default videojs skin. I tried few things but couldn't get it. Can you please help me ?